# DXA - Architecture and role of different services

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.4

Our team is working on DXA 1.4 & Web 8 combination. but since, DXA 1.3 went through some architectural changes. DXA [prerequisites](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v4/GUID-DD402008-D5C5-4DCA-A74F-893272D2B659) mentions use of certain services. so i have following questions on it.

Role of following different components

- SDL Web 8 Content Interaction Services (CIS)

  - .NET implementation of Content Delivery
  - Content Data Store Vs Content Service
  - Context Service
  - CWD dependency in Java version.

What are the optional services and can be disabled if specific functionality is not required.

any logical arch diagram of DXA will also help!

Answer (score 4):

Admittedly, the documentation of the DXA prerequisites is a bit unclear/confusing.

DXA is a Web Application Framework which builds upon the Content Delivery Architecture. For SDL web 8, it builds on the CD microservices architecture. In particular, it uses the following microservices:

- Discovery Service -- For authentication and lookup of the other microservices.
- Context Service -- To obtain Context Claims generated by the Context Engine (based on User-Agent header and context cookie).
- Content Service -- For everything else.  For an (XPM-enabled) staging site, you have to ensure you use the Session-Enabled Content Service.

The (Session-enabled) Content Service is backed by a Content Data Store, so that's not really a separate prerequisite, but you do have to ensure that your CD microservices are configured to store **everything** (also Pages and Binaries) the Content Data Store.

Comment: Why is context Service mandatory for DXA to run? Should n't it be optional. also what is role of CWD and CIS?